# Vim - Search and replace the results

Tags: search, vim, replace, find

I'm getting more and more comfortable with Vim after a few months.
BUT, there is only one simple feature I can't get any answer from the web. That is "Search and replace the results". The problem is that I know:

:/keyword to search, and hit enter "keyword" will be highlighted (of course with set hlsearch)
n, or N to navigate

:% s/keyword/new_keyword/g to replace all occurences of keyword with new_keyword.

BUT, I would think that there must be a way to search, and replace the matched keyword (highlighted) with any new_keyword WITHOUT doing ":% s/keyword/new_keyword/g", which is a lot of typing considering search & replace is such a day-to-day feature.

Any answers/comments will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you've already done a search you can do a substitution for the same pattern by simply leaving out the pattern in the substitute command. eg:

```
/keyword
```

searchs for "keyword", and then:

```
:%s//new_keyword/g
```

will replace all occurrences of "keyword" with "new_keyword".

Comment: This is great... didn't know about the empty search string using the previous search.  I would add though that search and replace is done so frequently that I would add some kind of mapping to do it for you such as: 
nmap <Leader>f :%s/\<<c-r>=expand("<cword>")<cr>\>/
That would search and replace for word the cursor is currently on... you could also have:
nmap <Leader>F :%s//
To use when you have already searched for something.

Answer (score 3):

Searching and using the dot command (you didn't meantion you are using the dot command, that's why I highlight it) to repeat the last input action is my best bet here.

I use s///g for search and replace.

Comment: Thanks Ronny, not as a efficient general solution for me BUT reminds me of an important Vim command ".". Cheers!!!

Answer (score 3):

Well, since #keyword# and #new_keyword# account for most of the characters, and you need some way to differentiate between them (i.e., a character in vim, or tab between entry fields in dialog in a different editor), you're left with maybe four or five keystrokes beyond that.

So I think you're probably overestimating number of keystrokes and also forgetting that (1) it becomes very natural, and (2) working this way allows you also to naturally modify the action performed by specifying a different range or option flag.

But you can cut down on keystrokes.  If you want you can map a key to automatically bring up the command line with '%s/' already in place.  e.g.:

```
nmap s :%s/
```

The command above would remap 's' (I'm not recommending remapping to that key, but it gives the idea) and set you up to insert the keyword.

Also, you can set the 'gdefault' option to default to substituting multiple times per line.  This lets you skip the ending '/g' in your keystrokes:

```
set gdefault
```

See ':h gdefault' for help section on that option.

In the end I would say just get used to the default way it works, because using it that way allows you to keep same basic operation when you want to specify different ranges or option flags, and creating a new special map is just another thing to remember.  gdefault may be worth setting if you think you're going to want it majority of time, adding /g flag at end when gdefault is set has effect of turning /g off. . .

Comment: Thanks a lot Herbert, lots of useful info and tips. Especially, I find set gdefault, and /g to dynamically unset is beautiful and wouldn't know. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

Move to the first highlighted word then record a macro for replacing the word and moving to the next one, e.g:

```
gg
n
qq
caw new_word^[
n
q
@q
@@
@@
...
```

Comment: That's a *hell* of a lot more typing than simply retyping the keyword into `:%s/.../.../g`

Comment: @meagar: true, but the question wasn't how to do it in the fewest keystrokes, just how to do it without :%s

Comment: @meagar: not when you can just press `.` to keep doing the same thing again.

Comment: @Codeninja He wasn't asking how to do it without `:%s`, he was asking how to do it *with* `:%s` but without retyping the keyword.

Comment: @Greg What if there are 1000 matches to replace?

Comment: I occasionally use ncw...n.n.n.(etc.) if I know there are only a few substitutions and I'm feeling really lazy. The closest situation where I use macros if there's something more complicated I need to replace. eg: the first occurrence of foo after each occurrence of bar (where foo and bar are on separate lines) with baz. That's where macro recording is really handy: `qq/bar<cr>/foo<cr>cwbaz<esc>q9999@q`

Comment: @meagar: I suppose I misinterpreted the question, oh well

Comment: Thanks Codeninja for a NINJA trick :D, and quite happy to see a little discussion going on here :D thanks dudes. Laurence's answer was what I wanted, but then it's my bad natural language that left some ambiguity. Anyway, thanks all for your time!!!