# Replace a line containing certain characters using vi

Tags: vim, vi

I'd like to replace all line containining "CreateTime=xxxxx"  with "CreateTime=2012-01-04 00:00".  May I know how should I do it with vim?

```
[m18]
Attendees=38230,92242,97553
Duration=2
CreateTime=2012-01-09 22:00

[m20]
Attendees=52000,50521,34025
Duration=2
CreateTime=2012-01-09 00:00

[m22]
Attendees=95892,23689
Duration=2
CreateTime=2012-01-08 17:00
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vim - Search and replace the results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082160/vim-search-and-replace-the-results)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the global substitute operator for this.

```
:%s/CreateTime=.*$/CreateTime=2012-01-04 00:00/g
```

You can read the help for the `s` command from within Vim using:

```
:help :s
```

You can read about patterns with `:help pattern-overview`.

As requested, a bit more about the regular expression match (`CreateTime=.*$`):

```
CreateTime=  # this part is just a string
.            # "." matches any character
*            # "*" modifies the "." to mean "0 or more" of any character
$            # "$" means "end of line"
```

Taken together, it matches `CreateTime=` followed by any series of characters, consuming the rest of the line.

Comment: can you please explain this part: .*$

Comment: @SagarJain I edited the answer with a bit more info on that.